# Problems with sessions and ColdFusion only in IE6

Tags: coldfusion, internet-explorer-6, session

We have a strange problem when implementing sessions with ColdFusion in IE6.

After login and after a refresh on the page all the session variables are lost.

Its some kind of config in the Administrator? Could you give me some troubleshooting tips to this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is session being stored by cookie?  This could cause it

Comment: Session isn't stored in cookies, but CF uses cookies to uniquely identify a browser and ties the session variables to it. If the CF cookie gets reset it is effectively clearing all of the session variables.

Comment: If you are using client variables from a datasource, this can happen if you have more than one server in a cluster and one of the data sources is configured incorrectly. 
For troubleshooting, take a look at your cftoken or cfid cookie. You should have a value corresponding to it in the client variables table (CDATA I think). After the next page refresh you should still have the same cftoekn/cfide, otherwise something is resetting the session. Some info here on client vars that might help: http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2007/1/23/client.variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this before, but it's been a long time. I remember creating a test page to dump out the cookies for the site and they'd change on every refresh. I don't remember if we ever found a solution. I want to say that the issue cleared up after another update from Microsoft, but it was so long ago I honestly don't remember.

What's happening is you're getting new values for the CFID and/or CFTOKEN cookies that CF creates and uses to keep track of the browser's state. (The web is by its nature stateless, but that's not very helpful when you need to do transactions.)

Here are some of the possible issues I've seen other people mention:

- Inconsistently using www.domain.com and domain.com. The site may work either way, but unless you're using domain cookies the cookies will care
- Privacy settings in IE being too restrictive
- Special characters in the domain name (underscore is mentioned specifically)
- Lack of P3P policy on the web server (back to the privacy settings)

As for solutions, have you tried using J2EE session variables? Some people have had success with those in solving this.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because your IE6 is not accepting cookies?

Comment: Hi Henry. Is accepting because we implemented cookies with javascript and it worked ok (we used this http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp).